# python: How do I expand a numpy array with adjacent duplicate columns?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

What I am trying to achieve is that I have a matrix like that:

```
axy
axy
axy
axy
```

And I want to expand that matrix so that it will become:

```
aaaxxxyyy
aaaxxxyyy
aaaxxxyyy
aaaxxxyyy
```

Is there a function that I can use to manage this transformation easily? I would like to use a better way than tiling each column separately and appending them back.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to alter the matrix or just print it that way?

Comment: Just for some matrix operations with another one, I don't further need that expanded version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [np.repeat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> b = np.repeat(a, 3, axis=1) # array, times, axis
>>> b
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]])
```